# curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54

Tags: dart, flutter

When I upgrade flutter, I came across with below error message.

> curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54

```
Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/4737fc5cd89b8f0136e927b00f2e159444b95a73/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
  https://flutter.io/community/china


Flutter 1.3.8 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e5b1ed7a7f (6 weeks ago) • 2019-04-11 14:01:46 -0700
Engine • revision 4737fc5cd8
Tools • Dart 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.0.0 571ea80e11)

Running flutter doctor...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 4737fc5cd89b8f0136e927b00f2e159444b95a73...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

What is this? what is the the problems?

Answer (score 12):

Run these commands, it should solve the problem.

```
echo '--no-alpn' > ~/.curlrc
export HOMEBREW_CURLRC=1
```

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html
--no-alpn

(HTTPS) Disable the ALPN TLS extension. ALPN is enabled by default if libcurl was built with an SSL library that supports ALPN. 
ALPN is used by a libcurl that supports HTTP/2 to negotiate HTTP/2 support with the server during https sessions. 

https://brew.sh/2018/04/09/homebrew-1.6.0/
Homebrew’s curl invocations now only read curlrc if HOMEBREW_CURLRC is set

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the file .curlrc or corresponding environment variable do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 10):

its a network issue. If your internet is very slow and there are hiccups with network, you will face this error. Try to run again

Answer (score 3):

VPN, if you are behind a firewall or using vpn, switch it off or ensure a good network connection.

Comment: I was using a proxy for another project, and forgotten to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

errno 54 is "Connection reset by peer", which basically indicates a generic network connectivity problem.

I've had this exact failure with `flutter upgrade` during a temporary wifi hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem trying to 'push' to GitLab.

Checked my account at GitLab website.  There were errors, unable to retrieve my files on the website.

After about 30 min, the GitLab website started retrieving files normally and 'push' started working.